# MBP 2011 A1278 multiple disks with multiple os installs

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, firmware

So... There's a MBP 2011 with an SSD and an HDD (in a caddy), the OS is on the SSD, and I don't know what is on the HDD (sorry, my girlfriend's computer). I suppose that the HDD is dying, she would like to downgrade the OS, because she wants this computer to freeze to 10.10 to use only for Aperture.

I think the easiest way to change the drives to a bigger SSD (the one in the mbp is an old 128gb, the HDD is the original 320gb), install the original OSX from apple recovery, and upgrade it to 10.10.

What will happen to the "bios"/firmware of the mbp, if I do like this? Can I change back to the original disks, the mbp should work as before? I'm newbie in Apple stuff, I use PC for a long time, sometimes with more than one disks with different OS installations, but I don't know, how does it work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I am not sure if you wish to migrate your existing installation on the 128 GB SSD to the new larger SSD. In other words, do you what a dual boot between Yosemite and your current OS X/macOS? If so update your question and include your current OS X/macOS.

You should not have to worry about the firmware, if you what to install an older version of OS X such as Yosemite. If you wish to install an larger internal SATA SSD, you might want to first create a bootable USB flash drive Yosemite installer. This can be done by the following steps.

Note: I tested the steps using a 2011 iMac booted from High Sierra.

1. Goto [How to download and install macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683#browser), then use your web browser to download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for Yosemite.
2. Open the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file. This will mount the `Install OS X` volume containing the `InstallMacOSX.pkg` file.
3. Open the `InstallMacOSX.pkg` file. This will create the Install OS X Yosemite application.
4. Follow the instruction from [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) to create a Yosemite bootable USB installer flash drive. The command to enter is given below.

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app
   ```

After installing the new internal SSD, use the following steps to install Yosemite.

1. Insert the flash drive.
2. Start the Mac and hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear.
3. Choose to boot from the flash drive.
4. Use the Disk Utility to Erase (Initialize) the new SSD. For format, use `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`. For scheme, use `GUID Partition Map`.
5. Install Yosemite.

### References

- [How to download and install macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683)
- [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)
- [About EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/101198)

Comment: Thank you for the flashdrive/installation instructions, they will be useful too.

The most important part of my question that if I change back the original ssd and hdd, the recent installation will work like right now?

Comment: For security reasons I thought that if I start from zero to an other ssd, I can keep the original state on the original drives, so it's reversible if I put back theese drives. Maybe the direct installation from a flash drive is a better way than the recovery+update. I'm uncertain, because I don't know the realation of the firmware and the os. Can I install different versions on different drives, and change the disk in the computer to use the version I need? I mean, separated installation on different disks. In this case one is that one on the two recent disk, the other one is the new one.

Comment: Our goal is a clear, new installation of 10.10 with Aperture 3.6, and that's all. We want to keep all the photos from the recent installation, so I think we should back up the recent user by Time Machine. I don't know the recent structure, I mean the /Home directory for example is on the 2nd drive (the hdd), or not, or where the aperture saves all the photos (I suppose, on the 2nd drive). If I back up the Aperture as an application, all the photos managed by will be backed up too? If now the application and the data stored on different disk, can I migrate to a single drive system?

Comment: Your comments have introduced new questions that did not exist in your posted question. I am not that familiar with Time Machine. Using Time Machine to backup under High Sierra and then to restore to an older version such as Yosemite might prove to be problematic.

Comment: Also, you are asking me questions that I can not possible answer. I do not know if the home directory is on the internal SSD or external HDD. Apparently, you do not know either. I (as well as others here a Ask Different) do not respond well to being asked to answer hypothetical questions. Especially, when posted in comments and not the original question itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's going to be a bunch of side questions but let's cover two things:

1. When you run the macOS update from an internal disk - you get the best chance that firmware updates. On older macs, there were standalone firmware updates you could run, but now that's mostly a thing of the past. If you need an update (usually for newer features / new OS support), then you want to get macOS installed and then run the upgrade of the OS from the internal drive.
2. It's always best to install the new OS first on an external drive - make sure you have a bootable install and then replace things on the internal / old system. It's much easier to read logs, fix things when you keep the bootable system around until you are done installing and migrating to the external drive that has the new OS. Then you can choose to set it as default or install that external drive internally. (or use ASR / Disk Utility to clone the external on to the internal drive).

Comment: To the 2nd point.

For the same reason I would like to do as I wrote. I don't touch the recent os, the recent disk, just I put them away. The question is that, if I install a different version of OSX, does that change anything in the firmware, or not? If I put back the original disks, the recent system will work like right now? The recent is 10.13 I think, the new one I want to install is 10.10.

Comment: Firmware won’t change until you a) run an explicit firmware update that says firmware b) choose to run a recent macOS update while connected to the internet and the pre update change downloads and installs a firmware update that’s available.

Comment: I do not believe any firmware update provided by Apple will prevent the installation of a version of OS X or macOS that Apple has stated is compatible with a given Mac. Pista should be able to at least install [Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8)](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp654?locale=en_US) through [High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6)](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp765?locale=en_US) on the 2011 MacBook Pro A1278.

Comment: Yes indeed @DavidAnderson I’ve not seen any reason to not update firmware or complete an install based on firmware - they are remarkably flat and cross compatible and not a blocker for basic OS operation the last decade plus - especially for a 2011 MacBook Pro specifically.